# Loki (64 bit only) on a Acer Aspire One Ao532h (ATOM N450)

Tags: system-installation

Im not an Ace in this things and I am a beginner on Linux but I would really appreciate your help since I would love quiting for good the microsoft sh*t. I guess by the posts I read my system is not suitable for Loki (64bit) since my Processor (ATOM N450) is a 32bit x86. Is it true? On the other hand, since there is not a 32bit loki version, can I use then a previous, let's say Freya, 32 bit version? Where can I get it (download it)? 
Thanks for helping this argentine elementary ignorant.
Regards

Fernando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your processor supports 64-bit. It should have a better performance than windows. Backup, save your windows key in case you need to reinstall and try a live usb before installing. If it works fine, go ahead and install.

:)

Comment: Source: http://ark.intel.com/products/42503/Intel-Atom-Processor-N450-512K-Cache-1_66-GHz. See the row labeled "instruction set."